# WPF - Disable unloading of items when scrolled in VirtualizingStackPanel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for a way to disable the items unloading when ItemsControl with VirtualizingStackPanel is scrolled.

What I am trying to achieve here is - Load initial set of items based on ItemsControl height and then load next set of items as we scroll down.

Any suggestion achieving this will be of great help.

Comment: Why do you need to disable the unloading? Isn't reusing the containers using `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`  good enough?

Comment: Thanks for the quicky. You are right and I have the same thought. I am basically working with a legacy project which is architected in such a way that, the moment control is unloaded its data context is set to null. So going with virtualization I will run into the situation where if item is some UI element and unloaded due to not being part of  ItemsControl's view area, I would never be able to revive it back.

So the best I thought I could do is to load the items in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnCleanUpVirtualizedItem(CleanUpVirtualizedItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UIElement != null)
        {
            //This is to suppress UI type editor disposal caused by virtualization.
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

In case anyone looking for such solution, override VirtualizedStackPanel's above method and cancel the cleanup process.